# Apache - Domain for localhost to access folders as http://folder.local

Tags: url, xampp, virtualhost

I'm running XAMPP on Ubuntu and I'd like to create a virtual host for my projects, so that I have a tld assigned to my server root directory (for example .local) and folders inside it accessible through URLs as `http://foldername.local`.

Also, how much more complicated would it be to use .htaccess to have `http://someotherdomain.local` redirect to the `/foldername` path in the server root?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to do it on my own. It is possible to do it, however you'll need to install a *DNS server*.

> Note: I decided to use .dev as my local domain, so in the following
>   examples, the `dev` part will refer to my chosen domain. Keep that in
>   mind.

#### Install and configure DNS Server

It shouldn't matter which one it is, but you'll need to know how to configure it properly. The configuration depends on which DNS server you chose. I went for ***dnsmasq***. It's lightweight and very handy.

> An important note for *Ubuntu* users is that since Ubuntu 11.10 there is
>   already a light version called *dnsmasq-base* installed, which will
>   cause conflicts during installation. I won't be explaining here how to
>   get around this, because there are many instructions available elsewhere.

Once you have your DNS server installed, you should configure it to listen for the address equal to your desired domain.

> In my case with *dnsmasq*, that meant opening `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and
>   changing line #62 to this: `address=/dev/127.0.1.1`

#### Configure Web server

Assuming that you already have some kind of Server software installed, you need to make a few tweaks.

First, you should edit your `hosts` file to map your desired domain to your localhost.

> in my case of XAMPP for Linux on Ubuntu, this means I opened
>   `/etc/hosts` and changed lines
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 localhost
> 127.0.1.1 tomica-ubuntu
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 localhost
> 127.0.1.1 tomica-ubuntu dev
> ```
>
> This will redirect `http://dev` to my local server.

Next, create a new virtual host with a couple of specific options, like this:

> In my case, that means opening
>   `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and adding this at the end of
>   the file:
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev"
>     ServerName dev
>     ServerAlias *.dev
>
>     <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/dev>
>         AllowOverride All
>     </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> For the sake of brevity, I won't explain this piece of code, since
>   documentation is also available.

After all this is done, start **your DNS and Web servers, or restart them** if they're already running.

#### Configure .htaccess

Open root folder of your newly created host. That's the folder devined in your . In my case, that's `/opt/lampp/htdocs/dev`. In there, create a `.htaccess` file and put this in it:

```
# Specify order of index files; if none exist, show files list
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

# Interpret .html files as .php scripts
  AddHandler php5-script .php .html

# THE MAGIC - Redirect subdomains of .dev to their respective folders
  RewriteEngine on
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dev$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.dev(.*)?$ [NC]
  RewriteRule !^%2\.dev%3?/$ http://dev/%2%{REQUEST_URI}/ [P]
```

Again, explaining all this would require too much space and time. Just copy/paste and don't worry :) But don't forget to change my `dev` to anything you chose for your domain name.

***AND THAT'S IT!*** By now you should be able to browse your project using addresses like `http://folder.dev/`, `http://www.folder.dev`, `http://folder.dev/file.html`, `http://folder.dev/subfolder/document.txt` etc.

As a bonus, I will add just one more advice. The reason why I did all this is so that I could more easily develop my Laravel and WordPress prjects. However, with Laravel, you should redirect the url `http://lvproject.dev/` to the location of `/lvproject/public`. And here is the `.htaccess` file that enables just that. Open your `/lvproject` folder, create a `.htaccess` file and place this code in it:

```
RewriteBase /lvproject/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} lvproject/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule index\.php(.*)$ public/ [L]
```

Two drawbacks of this solution are: 1) `RewriteBase` rule needs to be set anew for every new project (i.e. you need to manually create `.htaccess` in each new project); 2) Your project will be available from both `http://lvproject.dev/` and `http://lvproject.dev/public/`, which is not cool, but I'm too lazy at the moment to get it fixed :)

Comment: most if not all of these .htaccess rules could be integrated into the vhost config file.

Comment: @nullvariable that's good to know, thanks. In my case I was looking for a solution that would: a) not change my server's settings; b) work even if I moved my /htdocs folder to another server.