# .htaccess redirect dynamic domain to folder

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, virtualhost

For local development I've setup my router to redirect all requests to *.lan to my local xampp server. Now I have to setup virtual hosts for every domain I want to use. This works, but I don't want to setup a new virtual host (pointing to the corresponding folder) for every project and restart apache.

Is it possible to create a .htaccess file to "catch" a domain, and rewrite it to the folder, so I can use the domain as the folder name? For example:

example1.lan loads the website located in /example1/

example2.lan loads the website located in /example2/

This tread ( [Apache - Domain for localhost to access folders as http://folder.local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532263/apache-domain-for-localhost-to-access-folders-as-http-folder-local) ) does almost the same thing, but with a redirect. I don't want a redirect, I want rewrite.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root (the directory where the example1 and example2 directories are):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.lan$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
I figured it had to be something with $1 and %1, but this solution is only giving me 500 errors. I cleared my hosts file and restarted apache, but the 500 error stays.

Comment: @Wietse forgot a condition, try it now

Comment: Hi Jon,
Thanks for your efforts, but it doesn't seem to work; I still get the 500 error. Any ideas left?